# Full Disk Encryption: Swap Partition Not Used?

Tags: encryption, swap, partitioning

I followed the [ManualFullSystemEncryption](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption) guide to set up my ubuntu 18.04 system. It all worked well, and the result is I now have a fully operational Ubuntu install with FDE.

Part of my setup is a swap partition (which is on the encrypted system LVM: `/dev/mapper/system-swap`). I was investigating whether this swap partition is being recognized by the system as expected, because I want to enable hibernation on the system.

In doing so, I found e.g. forum posts like [this one](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392205), which mention checking `swapon -summary` to see if swap is available and enabled.
In my case, the output of that shows that not `/dev/mapper/system-swap` is being used for swap, but `/dev/dm-2` (and this isn't a symlink either):

```
$ swapon -summary
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-2                               partition   67108860    0   -2

$ ls -la /dev/dm-2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 2 Sep  2 21:53 /dev/dm-2

$ cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/system-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/system-boot /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=8621-89F0  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/data-home /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/system-swap none            swap    sw              0       0
```

#### My Question:

Is my system configured to use swap, or not? If so, is it indeed using the correct swap partition at `/dev/mapper/system-swap`? How can I tell?

Comment: See this device mapper used by LVM: https://superuser.com/questions/131519/what-is-this-dm-0-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do have swap enabled, and a quite big one at that, with 60GB+. Try hibernating and see how it goes.

Linux have several names for the same partition. The `/dev/dm-X` name is usually named sequentially, starting at 0, and adding one at each new partition mounted. In your case, it seems like dm-0 is your disk, and since you are using LVM, dm-1 is your root and dm-2 your swap. If you don't have another disk mounted, and you mount an encrypted usb, it will be dm-3, etc. It is generally used for encrypted partitions, from dmcrypt.

To see what each each partition represents, you have several alternatives. The simplest, would be `ls -alh /dev/mapper/`. You can also use `dmsetup`, using the info or ls options, and even `lvdisplay` for the partitions that are part of an LVM setup.